# Edit Text view increase its size when inserted long text in android

Tags: android, size, android-edittext, truncate

I have edittext view in my application but when  i insert long text in edit text this  increases view size.I  do not  want happened in my app because it created bad imapact on app so I decided  to use

```
android:singleLine="true" 
 android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLine="1"
```

xml attribute to the  edit text but it not worked for me .I don't have any idea how to prevent this from my problem.I did lot of R&D but i am not get satisfactory answer.Here is my Edit Text.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etaccountholdersname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvaccountholdername"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_input_field"
                android:hint="Account holder's name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
```

Here Is full code of Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerrel1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvaccountholdername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_account_holders_name_text"
                android:gravity="left" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etaccountholdersname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvaccountholdername"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_input_field"
                android:hint="Account holder's name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Please provide some help me to solve this issues.

Comment: Your code seems right. It shouldn't. Can you post screenshot and layout xml code as well.

Comment: What @ManishDubey said. Everything seems okay, the problem is coming from something else. Are you sure you are inflating that layout?

Comment: "increases view size" - You mean height or width?, Height shouldn't increase as it's singleline.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" try this

Comment: in code `getWidth` and `setMaxWidth` of EditText obviously :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout design you have "wrap_content" for both parent and children views. Make the parent layout width as static. If you working with multiple screens, use the dimens.xml for the sizes of the views in different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Use either android:layout_weight property or use android:ems="7"  it will work for you definetely

Comment: android:layout_weight  property is shown in relative layout

Comment: and i used android:ems="7" also but not success

Answer (score 0):

do not use

android:ellipsize="end"

its uses for textview

use
android:ems="10" (it limits edittext to show 10 charecters but you can insert many characters)

and you are good to go.